# How do I create another function to remove the appended form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  i=1; 
  function cloneDFLStep(){
    i++;
    
    var appendThis = '<hr><div id="formId" class="form-group"><label for="fa_title">Step '+i+'</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fa_title[]" name="fa_title[]"  placeholder="Enter Step Title ['+i+']"><br><textarea class="form-control" id="f_steps" name="f_steps[]" placeholder="Steps Description (Include All Steps Taken On Analysis) ['+i+']" rows="5"></textarea><br><textarea class="form-control" id="s_remarks" name="s_remarks[]" placeholder="Remarks (Add Any Remarks On Steps Taken) ['+i+']" rows="3"></textarea><hr><input class="minusbtn btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="button" name="removef" value="Delete Step ['+i+']"></div>';
    $('.appendRow').append(appendThis);

  }

</script>
```

This code appends a new form anytime the button is clicked. How Do I create a function to remove the new appended forms with the button created?

Comment: How is this related to PHP or angular?

Comment: If your function is called more than once, you'll get multiple HTML elements with the same id's, which is invalid in HTML. Id's _must_ be unique within a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrap the string you stored in `appendThis` with `$()`, so you have an jQuery set of (not rendered) elements which you can operate on.
2. Bind a click event to the `minusbtn` class of your created delete button
3. Delete all previously rendered elements (=> stored in `appendThis`) inside the click event.

**See this Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/z9d8nphm/

Extended Code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  i=1; 
  function cloneDFLStep(){
    i++;
    
    // ATTENTION. STRING WRAPPED HERE: var $appendThis = $(...) 
    var $appendThis = $('<hr><div id="formId" class="form-group"><label for="fa_title">Step '+i+'</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fa_title[]" name="fa_title[]"  placeholder="Enter Step Title ['+i+']"><br><textarea class="form-control" id="f_steps" name="f_steps[]" placeholder="Steps Description (Include All Steps Taken On Analysis) ['+i+']" rows="5"></textarea><br><textarea class="form-control" id="s_remarks" name="s_remarks[]" placeholder="Remarks (Add Any Remarks On Steps Taken) ['+i+']" rows="3"></textarea><hr><input class="minusbtn btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="button" name="removef" value="Delete Step ['+i+']"></div>' );

    $appendThis.find( '.minusbtn' ).click( function( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $appendThis.remove();
    });

    $('.appendRow').append($appendThis);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank You...initially i was thinking of another function outside the cloneDFLStep() function but it works perfectly how i want it... thank you

Comment: @Sniffedpcs Glad to hear it! If this answer helped you, can you please mark this question as answered, for future reader :)

Comment: how do i go about that please?

Comment: @Sniffedpcs There is a check mark on each answer, which you can click to mark the answer as accepted :) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="appendRow"></div>

<button onclick="cloneDFLStep()">cloneDFLStep</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  i=1; 
  function cloneDFLStep(){
    i++;
    
    var $appendThis = $('<hr><div id="formId" class="form-group"><label for="fa_title">Step '+i+'</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fa_title[]" name="fa_title[]"  placeholder="Enter Step Title ['+i+']"><br><textarea class="form-control" id="f_steps" name="f_steps[]" placeholder="Steps Description (Include All Steps Taken On Analysis) ['+i+']" rows="5"></textarea><br><textarea class="form-control" id="s_remarks" name="s_remarks[]" placeholder="Remarks (Add Any Remarks On Steps Taken) ['+i+']" rows="3"></textarea><hr><input class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" id="removeForm" type="button" name="removef" value="Delete Step ['+i+']"></div>' );
    $appendThis.children( '#removeForm' ).click(function(){ 
   $appendThis.remove();
  })
    $('.appendRow').append($appendThis);

  }

</script>
```

Comment: I think we can solve this problem adding the From remove function in your script
then, after created form with remove button, if remove button is clicked, form will be removed

Comment: The problem is that the `cloneDFLStep()`-function, if called more than once, will generate multiple elements with the same id's so if you select the element by the id, it won't be the last element that gets selected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).